# Can't override bootstrap .navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I overrided .navbar from bootstrap like this :

```
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

It works well for some times, but because of an error I had to rewrite my css file entirely which is now like this :

```css
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

I took all of the template except .footer and .navbar on a website. As I said, it was like this before and everything worked fine.

The only portion of code where I use the navbar class is this one :

```
        {% block header %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <div class="navbar-brand-name">
                            <img alt="logo" width="80%" height="80%" src="bundles/exportail/images/logo.png" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                   <p class="navbar-text"> Connected as : {{ app.user.username }}
                       -
                       <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Disconnected</a>
                   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
   {% endblock %}
```

When I examine this div with the google inspection tools, it presents me the margin at 20px (default value) even if I had already overrode the value in my .css. 
I called my .css like this :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="bundles/exportail/css/pagelayoutonline.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   {% endblock %}
```

I already did some search and the net and I did not find anything really helpful ... If you have any clue, I will appreciate it !

Comment: is it live? can you post the link of your site?

Comment: put the link to your custom css after the link to bootstrap's css if you don't bootstrap's css will override the css in your custom css file

Comment: Many thanks Drinkin People ... It works !

Comment: @DrinkinPeople you should post an answer so Ecterion can accept it.